# Order on a second column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to order my table by a second column.

I know that there are attributes like `sortList`, `sortForce` and `append`.
`sortList` and `sortForce` helped me to get my goal by a half.

My goal: I want to order my entries like in the Windows file explorer.

If you sort by a col ascending, all folders are display in order and than comes the files in order.

If you sort by a col descending, all files are display in desc order and than comes the folders in descending.

I have created a hidden column to solve this problem for the ascending ordering.
This column get the type of the "entry" (file|dir). It got the `forceSort` attribute.

But it is always order in the same direction. I want to change it to the order direction of the new clicked column.

Long story short: no matter which column header was clicked, i want first order the hidden "type" column" and than the clicked column in the same direction, which the click column will have.

Could anyone assist me here?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JKjTp/3/)

Comment: Can you post your relevant code here or even jsfiddle if possible

Comment: @dreamweiver i will build something for. wait a moment. [at]blazemonger: this will only help for the initial sorting

Comment: Im seriously not getting what your trying to say :(

Comment: I suppose you are sorting your rows serverside using ajax ?? If not, you should maybe look in this direction.

Comment: i've added a fiddle for it

Comment: @TCHdvlp this is what i'm doing, when i load the table. but i want to order it via JS after the ajax load, if the users clicks on a column header. i want to avoid to reload the whole table

Comment: so, you are ordering it via an attribute, right ? Depending the header you have clicked, you re-order your table swich an attribute. Why don't put the string "dir" or "file" at the begining of this attr ? As "dir" is before "file" in the alphabetic order, you will have directories before files, both ordered in alphabetic order and vise versa. ex : "dir-aaa" > "dir-xxx" > "file-ddd" > "file-zzz" in a descending order

Comment: tablesorter is a jquery plugin, which i'm using. i need a solution with this plugin. the plugin is not sorting by an attribute. it is sorting the values by the text-value of each td-element

Comment: but you got a good point there. i'm using now a hidden span-tag and it works, what i didn't expected. thanks

Comment: but know it is still complecated, cause the plugin can't detect the date correct anymore. i'm still seeking for a better solution. mybe with build in functions of the table sorter.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to make sure you are using [Mottie's fork of Tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html).  Version 2.3+ supports [multi-column sorting](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-header-column-span.html), which will accomplish what you need, I believe.